# ng-click find json array item and populate form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an ng-repeat that I want to assign an ng-click for that particular row of data and populate my form using that particular json array item.

I need to find the json array "site_id" and populate the form with the "site_code" associated with it.

http://plnkr.co/edit/d44YNelPByM3ZTibKe8W

html:

```
  <div data-ng-repeat="site in sites track by $index">

    <a href="" data-ng-click="linkToSite()">
      {{site.site_id}}
    </a>

  </div>
  <input type="text" name="site_code" data-ng-model="data.site_code">
```

json:

```
[
  {
  "site_id": "ID 1234",
  "site_code": "Code abc"
  },
  {
  "site_id": "ID 5678",
  "site_code": "Code xyz"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to pass the `site` to the `$scope.linkToSite` method.

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="linkToSite(site)">
  {site.site_id}}
</a>
```

Then, handle the argument in the method, and implement the method assigning the site to a new `$scope` property, say `$scope.selectedSite`:

```
$scope.linkToSite = function (site) {
  $scope.selectedSite = site;
};
```

Finally, you can use `selectedSite` in the second part of your template:

```
<p>
  <input type="text" name="site_code" data-ng-model="selectedSite.site_code">
</p>
```

Here is the plnkr of the solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZbdHuR9GbIkGYLsAju3y?p=preview

And the full solution code:

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $log) {

  $http.get('myJson.json')
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.sites = data;
  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // alert('http error');
  });

  $scope.linkToSite = function (site) {
    $scope.selectedSite = site;
  };
});
```

View

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div data-ng-repeat="site in sites track by $index">

    <a href="" data-ng-click="linkToSite(site)">
      {{site.site_id}}
    </a>

  </div>

  <hr />
  <h4>Populate input with site_id from link above.</h4>
  <label for="site_code">Site Code</label>

  <p><input type="text" name="site_code" data-ng-model="selectedSite.site_code"></p>

  <input type="submit" ng-click="save()" value="Save and reset" />



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Send it the data through the function:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="linkToSite(site.site_code)">
  {{site.site_id}}
</a>
```

then in your ng-click function you want to assign the proper data to that model:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.linkToSite = function(code) {
    $scope.data.site_code = code;
}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bie1cCPLiAwyJBRb4FHx?p=preview)